# Criticizing Arguments: Identifying Weaknesses

Tags: critique-of-pure-reason, critical-thinking, critque-of-judgment

> I have recently gained interest in Philosophy as I quite arbitrarily came across an interesting video on YouTube discussing the importance of Philosophy and how it evolved throughout history.

I more specifically, found it interesting because it surprisingly, finally started to help me define a person's rationality and understanding of life. So, I have decided to find a guide and learn it myself on my free time (here it is for those who are interested! https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhilosophyFAQ/comments/4ifqi3/im_interested_in_philosophy_where_should_i_start)

To cut to the chase, I started following the guides in that tutorial, and I wanted to complete one of the tasks specified in there and try to analyze an article (list all the flaws made by the author). However, I don't really know where to start, and what to think about when I'm analyzing it. Here is the [article](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/limits-of-the-far-right-three-lessons-from-the-dutch-election/article34321930/).

Could somebody perhaps give me a hand with how to approach it? Or maybe help me analyze it so I'll have some sort of an example, and I could try applying the same principles on different articles in the future? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). Please be aware that [questions are subject to editing and closure](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. Additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: on the "importance of philosophy" -- i was talking with a geographer -- not so recently -- and they said that they [geographers] were always doing what philosophers advised.

Comment: This is a pretty good site on Bertrand Russell.  https://users.drew.edu/jlenz/br-lay-philosophy.html

Comment: What is a good essay? Here I am not talking about content, but I am speaking of method and style. If you know what is good, it helps you to criticize what may be bad. So what is good? You may want to see the work by Sartre “Existentialism is a Humanism”. Per Prof. Vincent Spade: “At first, you may think Sartre’s essay is rather loose and rambly. But actually it has a fairly tight structure. (In fact, if you want to know, it fits the classical mediaeval quaestio-form of objections, discussion, reply to objections.)” https://www.pvspade.com/Sartre/pdf/sartre2.pdf